# how to use C# compiler to analyze text in a textbox? (possible lexical analysis)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compiler-construction, ide

Im writing a simple code editor just like visual studio code editor.
btw i have a textbox and wanna know how can i underline syntactical errors?

i`v searched the web, but did not find something usefull. any one got any refernce of documentation for C# compiler to help me in this topic?
thanks all and sorry for my bad english..

Comment: There are tools already available for this. Why are you re inventing the wheel? Use `AvalonEdit` or such kind of editors which also provides intellisense too

Comment: "Sriram Sakthivel" thanks for the comment but i want to do it as a case study.

Comment: This is a fairly complex topic. Thinking of using a compiler to do this job is quite naive. The problems are a) most of the time the code shown in the editor is **not** syntactically valid at several places at once, b) you cannot afford to recompile everything every now and then because of performance. Compilers expect valid code and don't need to excel in recovery from errors. Syntax highlighters work in exactly opposite conditions.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655 this help you, `CompilerError` class tells where exactly the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this for a real-world scenario, there are good commercial options available. You need to look at using the CodeDom classes which can take your input text and convert it into an object model which can then be compiled into an assembly.

If there are compiler errors, they will be returned as a collection of `CompilerError` objects. These will tell you the line number, character number, and error message, so you can display the error.

There are significant drawbacks to using `CodeDom`, however. It is older technology and has not been updated to keep pace with the language changes so there are limitations in what it can parse. If you want to write your own parser, you need to look at language tools like lexx and yacc or [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx).

Comment: thanks Scott. dose visual studio use this method? because i`v used this in the past its slow. but visual studio one isnt that slow.

Comment: No, Visual Studio uses what's called a "language service", which hooks in to the actual language compiler to do the parsing. This would be most similar to using Roslyn.

Answer (score -2):

With a simple textbox control you certainly cannot do that. At least you need to use a RichTextBox control (comes in a variety of flavors, for WPF, WinForms, from Office...), to do some code formatting. As a first exercise, I would suggest you try to color keywords in your editor. That's a fairly easy task (and error recovery is not a problem) and may show you how to use the control.

Comment: Syntax highlighting and formatting have nothing to do with lexical parsing.

Comment: the textbox control (or any control isnt the case) i have a good text editor already written by myself.

Comment: @ScottDorman: I know, but the OP is asking "i have a textbox and wanna know how can i underline syntactical errors?". I thought this was the problem here.